# jQuery File Upload (Blue imp) Symfony 2 405 method not allowed

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, blueimp

I am using this bundle for a multi file upload in my symfony 2 project :

https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle

in combination with this plugin :

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

The upload itself is working but i also get this error in my console:

```
GET http://localhost/vdvinfra/web/app_dev.php/_uploader/gallery/upload 405 (Method Not Allowed)
665832b_jquery-2.0.3.min_1.js:6 x.support.cors.e.crossDomain.send665832b_jquery-2.0.3.min_1.js:6 x.extend.ajax7b52311_main_9.js:61 (anonymous function)665832b_jquery-2.0.3.min_1.js:4 l665832b_jquery-2.0.3.min_1.js:4 c.fireWith665832b_jquery-2.0.3.min_1.js:4 x.extend.ready665832b_jquery-2.0.3.min_1.js:4 S
```

Because of that the plugin is not working as it should be. (Not showing progress bars or messages).

The bundle says in its documentation that i need to make a route in my routing.yml like this:

```
oneup_uploader:
    resource: .
    type: uploader
```

config.yml :

```
oneup_uploader:
mappings:
    gallery:
        frontend: blueimp
```

my simple input field:

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="{{ oneup_uploader_endpoint('gallery') }}" multiple />
```

my javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(function () {
            $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                dataType: 'json',
                done: function (e, data) {
                    $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
                        $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
                    });
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

I already changed the route methods to post, put and get. 
Still not working.

I wonder if anyone can solve this problem!

Thanks

Comment: Hello, show please you controller

Comment: Fixed by using another plugin( dropzone ) so this is not needed anymore. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What web server do you use? I suggest it is Nginx. You have to fix your config file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use Apache 2.2 so this is not problem. I guess it is something in symfony and it's routing methods.

Comment: Anyway, there is a problem with post method in Nginx, so I thought you have problem with config :)