# OneupUploaderBundle(blueimp), - Method Not Allowed

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I used OneupUploaderBundle with frontend blueimp. I see nice frontend, but I have problem with backend. In jsconsole is:

> GET XXX/web/app_dev.php/_uploader/gallery/upload 405 (Method Not
>   Allowed)

In documentation jQuery File Upload, we read that it should send by POST.

Why is GET and how I can change it?

services.yml

```
services:
    Cms.upload_listener:
        class: Cms\AdminBundle\EventListener\UploadListener
        arguments: [@doctrine]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oneup_uploader.post_upload, method: onUpload }
```

config.yml

```
oneup_uploader:
    mappings:
        gallery:
            frontend: blueimp
```

routing.yml

```
oneup_uploader:
    resource: .
    type: uploader
```

I'm using the default template with website blueimp, episode:

```
<form id="fileupload" data-url="{{ oneup_uploader_endpoint('gallery') }}" action="{{ oneup_uploader_endpoint('gallery') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

When I used Google Poster and sent by POST, I saw json, so problem is with configuration.

Thank you!

Comment: @fred-ii I'm using the default template with website blueimp. Add code in first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used:

```
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/cmsadmin/jQuery-File-Upload/js/main.js')}}"></script>
```

I must use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin used may not be your best solution here, if implementing a plugin is giving you errors and you are not alone :

[jQuery File Upload (Blue imp) Symfony 2 405 method not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28536768/jquery-file-upload-blue-imp-symfony-2-405-method-not-allowed?rq=1)

Better use another one like dropzone :

http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration